# Much better performance (reading) for INT type than SMALLINT

Tags: database, postgresql, sqldatatypes, postgresql-9.5

I have a table with 1.3 million rows

I had `smallint` (indexed) column this table, and when I was runing very simple query:

```
select * from table where field = x order by id limit 100
```

sometimes (when I was changing x with different values) query was very slow (10-20 seconds sometimes).

Then I altered this column with `int` type, and also created index on this column.

Now, same queries are much faster than previous, almost always, they takes not more than 1 second.

So, `smallint` takes less space on disk, but reading on `int` type, is much better performed.

It's right? if so, Why?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible test case so I can try it out?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably either data skew or stale index statistics.

The first is the distribution of values.  If there are only a few values in the column, then Postgres is smart enough not to use the the index.  So, it depends on the selectivity of the index.

The same thing can happen if the index statistics need to be updated.

It is highly unlikely that the difference in data types would be driving this.  More likely, the fresh index that is created has up-to-date statistics.

Comment: There is approximately 5000 unique values in field. For both cases, index was sometimes used, sometimes not, but `int` type is much faster than was `smallint`. Also I was refreshing old (`smallint`) index (dropped and recreated) but anyway, some queries was still slow for  `smallint` type

Comment: The difference in index size and possibly alignment of values could result in a difference of performance.  But it wouldn't result in orders of magnitude shifts, where the slower version takes multiple seconds.  The real issue is whether the index is getting used.